# IE9 better developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

IE9 offers some developer tools when you hit F12 but those don't offer any functionality interesting to me. I need an option to freely update HTML and CSS and they make it difficult.

Is there any "Firebug" for IE? Or at least Google Chrome like developer tools.

Answer (score 5):

There is Firebug Lite which is JavaScript based and should work on most browsers:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

It does not offer all the tools that the real Firebug does, but its a step forward.

Also I have found the IE developer tools not *too* bad. However I only use them for cross browser fixes.

Comment: I used to use IE9 tools, too (they have nice JS console) but today I encountered error that simply can't be investigated and fixed without better functionality :) Thank you for firebug lite link.